# Cordova angular app saving data to device

Tags: angular, cordova, breeze

My app is an Angular SPA built with cordova to run on android devices. For data access and caching I'm using BreezeJS. This is all hanging together ok.

The issue is saving the data to the device so that if the user closes the app they can open it again in the same state as they left it. This involves saving the data from the breeze cache to the device and restoring it.

I'm hooking onto the "pause" event to detect when the app is closing and then saving the data to the device. This will happen as soon as the app goes into the background.

```
document.addEventListener("pause", quitCordova, false);
```

The problem is if the user minimizes then closes, but opens the app immediately (repeats a couple of times) then I think the restore happens on a file that hasn't been completely saved yet corrupting the data.

You don't seem to be able to delay to ensure the save has actually finished before reading the file again.

Heres how the data is being saved:

```
var fs = CordovaPromiseFS({
                persistent: true, // or false
                storageSize: 90857600,
              });

fs.write(myKey, myData).then(successFunction).catch(failureFunction);
```

That CordovaPromiseFS is a wrapper to the file system, details here https://github.com/markmarijnissen/cordova-promise-fs

Comment: what type of data you want to save to device `Ex: ['Image', 'PDF', 'JSON', 'OTHER']`

Comment: the data being saved is currently in string format, it is the data from the breeze cache (basically the database). You can optionally save it as JSON too though

Comment: If nothing else works, you may need to write the data based on events within your application (e.g. user actions), so it will be done before `pause` occurs.

Comment: Yes @SteveSchmitt I'm thinking the same, currently changes are stored in the local cache and only saved to device on the pause but we could write to device on every state change, although there will be a slight performance hit doing this.